# Unable to upload a file in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I'm unable to set path in function of `setDestination()` to upload a file in zend framework.

My file is successfully uploaded, when I use path like:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->setDestination("C:/");
```

but actually I want to upload a file in directory say `upload_folder` which is in public directory in zend framework. I have tried my codes as:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();            
$upload->setDestination($this->view->baseUrl()."/upload_folder/");
```

but the file is not uploaded in the above path directory.

Can anyone help me? How to set path for file upload in `Project_Directory/public/upload_folder`?

Comment: you should accept the answer that helped you. that is the least you should do.

Answer (score 3):

`setDestination` would require a filesystem path, hence why `C:/` works and using `baseUrl` doesn't.

`$this->view->baseUrl` would be `http://yourserver.com` (that's a URL, not a filesystem path).

If you've setup your Zend Framework like most of the examples, you should have an `APPLICATION_PATH` variable set to e.g. `C:/project/application` (you would also have `C:/project/public` for example).

If you do have `APPLICATION_PATH` (just echo it to see where it goes), then you can use `setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/upload_folder/');`

Answer (score 1):

set the upload path using `APPLICATION_PATH` constant

```
setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/upload_folder/')
```